# Pc Need to restart.... While installing windows

Tags: windows-8

Yesterday my computer showed blue screen of death. Windows stopped working after that. Now, I am trying to install windows 8 via USB but while installing windows, on "Getting files ready for installation : 4%" my pc shows blue screen and text "your pc ran into a problem and needs to restart......
search online NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM for more information"
I tried installing windows again amd again but can't solve this problem.
(Sometimes PC automatically restart without showing any blue screen)

[image]

Comment: If I saw something like that I'd immediately think hard disk corruption or failure, particularly as it's happening during installation.  I never used Windows 8.  Does the USB have disk tools on it so you can run scans?

Comment: Hey stephen. I have normal USB. I just create my usb bootable and trying to install windows.

Comment: I'd bet money you have a hard drive failure, but as-is there's not enough information here.  Start testing your hardware.  VTC.

Comment: I tried installing on 4 different Hard drives. All hard drives were working properly but when I installed it in my PC, I still cannot install windows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is Hard Disk Master Boot Record/MBR failure/corrupt. I've dealt with hard drive corruption caused by several quick power outages, and so have a little experience.

Googling the error code I learned "The 0x00000024: NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM stop code usually means that your harddrive file system or the harddrive itself is broken so you'll want to run diagnostics on the disk. But if problems persist after running the error checking, the hdd is probably broken"

Comment: Checking a bad file system is cheaper/easier than replacing the hard drive. So the first step should be to use a bootable disk utility to wipe the drive of any preexisting partitions, scan it for errors, and then initialize it and try running the installation again.